# Bind command to TreeViewItem based on the type of the underlying object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

My `TreeView` contains objects of type `ServerItem`, which in turn contains objects of type `DatabaseItem`. Xaml looks like this:

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ServerItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ConnectServer}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Databases}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Now - binding to `ConnectServer` works ok, but I have another command - `ConnectDatabase`, and I want it to be executed when the user double clicks `TreeViewItem` contained by `ServerItem`'s `TreeViewItem`. In other words - is it possible to bind commands in WPF based on the object type (so that first level items would have other command bindings than second level, third level (and so on) items)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ItemTemplateSelector.

By using this technique in combination with multiple Hierarchical DataTemplates you should meet your goal.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Sorry for not reading your reply.
Do you still searching for a solution?